# How to lock screen while playing games?

Tags: lock-screens

I am wondering is there any app or a robust way of locking screen (front keys as well) while playing games in android phone. Is there any common app for locking/disabling the keys/touch when we play videos, youtube, playing games or reading ebook etc.

The phone should go in lock mode as if by pressing lock button on side panel, and pressing it should prompt us to unlock the device. My LG L90 D410 has this built-in feature for playing local videos but not for other apps, games and youtube videos.

Comment: What do you mean locking screen? Are you referring to locking the screen the way it happens when power button is pressed once, which puts the device to sleep and turns off the display? Or do you want to freeze the functioning of hardware buttons when you're playing a video or reading a book so that they don't interfere in your content consumption? If it is the former case (and the first answer addresses it), then I'm curious why do you need such functionality? If it's the latter case, then the words needs to be refined. Also, in the latter case, why do you want to freeze touch input?

Comment: @Firelord, it might be that he wants drastic measures to prevent unauthorized usage of his device, e.g. by his 8-year old kid spending 15 hours a day  with videos and games (no offense intended, just an example)

Comment: ha, my kid is not of 8 years old, merely approaching 2. Yea because of his mobile usage, i asked such question here. When he plays some game,  for example pressing home key accidentally will take him right out of current game to home screen and its very annoying. So we just want to stop this no-sense.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, here's how to do it using [Tasker](http://tasker.dinglisch.net):

1. Install Tasker
2. Create a new Task called lock screen, add an action to it as via

Display → System Lock

3. Create a profile and add as context to it all games in the apps list it provides, or as you need it.
4. Link the lock screen task to this profile.

Your device should lock up now if you try to open any marked app.

Note: Tasker is a paid app. Also, the trigger system lock functionality needs you to allow Tasker as a device administrator.

Edit:

I figured out how to do this using [MacroDroid](http://www.macrodroid.com/), which is free for a limited feature set.

1. Install MacroDroid and open it.
2. Tap on create new macro
3. Select Application launched/closed from the trigger list.
4. Select application launched from the popup
5. Choose the required apps from the list.
6. Choose the action as screen on/off.
7. Choose screen off from the popup
8. Press the tick button.
9. On the constraints page, leave it at none and press the tick button.
10. Enter a relevant name for the macro and press OK in the resulting popup.

This worked for me. Again, this needs the app to be a device administrator, which will be indicated to you as you select the screen off action, for similar reasons as above.

Comment: oh dear! its paid; can you not find any useful free app to solve my query? I'm happy with ads.

Comment: Sorry. There is an app called macrodroid, but since I have only used Tasker I can only help you with it. Let me check

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand what you're getting at, but have you considered "Screen pinning"? It's a built-in feature in android 5.0 and up. When this setting is turned on you can keep the current screen in view until you unpin it by holding Back and Overview buttons at the same time. This feature can be accessed at:

Setting -> Security -> Screen pinning

Comment: My current device is Redmi Note 4 (SD) and it doesn't have any Screen Pinning option :(